# Need to manually set resolve.conf after successfull VPN install

Tags: network-manager, dns, vpn, systemd-resolved

As many have done in recent weeks I tried to get VPN up and running and working from home now.

After a lot of struggle, I managed. We're using L2TP/IPsec VPN.

Installing:

[xl2tpd](https://github.com/xelerance/xl2tpd) from github (needed a special flag for companies firewall, WATCHGUARD)

```
network-manager-l2tp

network-manager-l2tp-gnome
```

I had major issues. I tried everything, to the point I have no idea what I did. Our VPN only supported `3des-sha1-modp1024` which I saw requesting. I read somewhere Linux simply doesn't support that, he started to accept `aes-sha256-modp1024`. And it worked.

BUT, I have to manually re-arrange the DNS servers in `/etc/resolve.conf`, setting my companies DNS at the top. In a file that says `DO NOT EDIT` this file.

Now the issue is I don't get the DNS I need to connect to companies dev-websites. I know I did some change to `resolve.conf`, somewhere, something about a symlink that I set.

TL;DR: I want my DNS servers to update automatically when connecting to VPN after fiddling around in root to destruction without knowing what I did.

Extra logs:

```
$ ls -l /etc/resove.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 mar 17 10:00 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

```
$ lbs_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco
```

Comment: Hi.  What version of ubuntu are you running?  Can you post the command to start the vpn and the terminal output resulting from this?

Comment: As well as the output of command `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`, please.

Comment: I've updated my post. I don't have the logs from the VPN. Is it logging `journal-ctl -f`?

Comment: How do you start your vpn?  Is it done from the command line, and in that case, what is the output you get in the terminal?  (that was what I meant in my first question)

Comment: I turn it on in the network settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 19.10 I had also failing installs of DNS servers on an ipsec vpn.  It was solved by installing package resolvconf.
    `sudo apt-get install resolvconf`
    `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`
In the last step use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to move between selections and <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to select (enter).  Configure to prepare for dynamic updates.

Comment: Thank you kind stranger. It worked.

Comment: you are most welcome